# Evitar que un archivo se sobrescriba utilizando writeFile

Tags: javascript, fs

[image: El codigo]

Hola! estoy tratando de crear un archivo mediante un constructor, pero no logro evitar que se vuelva a sobrescribir cada vez que ejecuto el código, por lo que a la hora de hacer un push al objeto y añadirlo dentro del .txt se me reinicia todo.

Seguramente sea algo sencillo pero no logro verlo

Comment: Quita la imagen y deja código para que sea mejor vista tu pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por defecto el `flag` de escritura es `w` lo que indica que el archivo se va a sobrescribir. Puedes cambiarlo por `a+` que significa abrirlo para leerlo o agregarle datos. Puedes usar el tercer parámetro para especificar el modo:

```
fs.writeFile("'./productos.txt', '', { flag: "a+" }, error => {
    ...
});
```

Aqui mas información acerca de los flags: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#file-system-flags

Comment: Muchas gracias!